# vba email files to single recepient from list

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have table (see below) from which my macro based on set condition sending emails with attachement.

[image: Table with results and conditions]

what I want is that if the codition numbers are same as on example in the table 2_3803063 (two rows), macro will send to user 3803063 one email with two invoices those are in first column.

what I have now is code which is sending if condition is 1, one invoice per one user

```
For Each cell In wsA.Range("A3:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    '~~> codition 1
        If cell.Offset(0, 5) = "1" Then

'~~> vlookups for email ged email based on custmer number
        i = cell.Value

        cnum = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i, tablear, 8, False) '~~> get customer number

        processor = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(cnum), r, 4, False) '~~> get customer mail


        If processor Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            strbody = "Dear Customer," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please find attached credit note/add bill for your attention." _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Billing Department" _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "*Please do not reply on this email. If you require further information please contact us on *"


            With OutMail
                .To = MeMail 'processor
                .Subject = "Emailing Document " & cell.Value
                .body = strbody

          '~~> send file from back up folder if backup exists
            If cell.Offset(0, 4) <> "Backup found" Then
                .Attachments.Add topath & cell.Value & ".pdf"
            Else
                .Attachments.Add backup & cell.Value & ".pdf"
            End If

'                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
'                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
'                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
'                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
'                        End If
'                    End If
'                Next FileCell

                .send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
      End If
    Next cell
```

Update: I found one code yesterday and modify it but I am not entireyly satisfied with it since. Email is taken from different sheet or will be base on invoice number there is Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup which is than returning email. The test below does not have vlookup implemented yet.

```
    Sub Test1()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim r As Long

    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsA = wbI.Sheets(Invoices)
    Set tbl = wsA.ListObjects("tblInput")

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    topath = "U:\path\IE Macro\PDF\" & Year(Date) & "\"
    r = 3

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
lastRow = shtInput.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In wsA.Range("A3:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

          If Left(cell.Offset(0, 5), 1) = "2" Then
               ' tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=cell.Offset(0, 5).Value

                With rng
                    '~~> Some Filter. Change as applicable
                    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="2*"

                    '~~> Get the filtered range
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                End With


    Do While r <= rng.Rows.count
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = meMail '~~> constant with string
            .Subject = rng.Cells(r, 3).Value & " Report"
            .HTMLBody = ""
           .Attachments.Add (topath & cell.Value & ".pdf")
            'See if the next row is for the same client.  If so, process that
            'row as well.  And then keep doing it until no more rows match
            Do While (rng.Cells(r, 6).Value = rng.Cells(r + 1, 6) And Left(rng.Cells(r, 6), 1) = 2)
                r = r + 1
                '.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</br>" & "This is how much was spent on the " & rng.Cells(r, 3).Value & " account:" & rng.Cells(r, 4).Value
                .Attachments.Add (topath & rng.Cells(r, 1).Value & ".pdf")
            Loop
            .send

        End With
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        r = r + 1
    Loop

        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=6
    End If
Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: As you have not shown the email column and you are checking the email format, what happens if the first row has the email but the second row either doesn't have an email or has an email that doesn't match the email in the first row? Or do you just send all attachments to the email in the first row?

Comment: Use a for loop to add attachment more than 1.

Comment: Can you post full code ?

Comment: Hi I added another code whic is doing the trick but its not ideal I think...

Comment: I would say the problem not big but still is the for each cell because after sending mail it goes to this loop again and check another cell value but then in do while r<= rng.rows.count it will skip it because r is already smaller which is good